# "If statement" deleted, c code runs without problem, what is the reason?

Tags: c, if-statement, do-while, swap, greatest-common-divisor

When the if statement is deleted, the code runs without problems. What is the reason for that? This code gives the Greatest Common Divisor (GCD) of two numbers (m and n) the user should input.

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main() {
    int m, n, r;
    scanf("%d,%d", &m, &n);

    if (m < n) {
        r = m;
        m = n;
        n = r;
    }

    do {
        r = m % n;
        m = n;
        n = r;
    } while (r != 0);

    printf("%d\n", m);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: What is your exact input?

Comment: When the if statement is not deleted, does it work or does it fail?   You don't have to do the swap — the GCD algorithm does that on the first pass if `m < n`.  So the presence of the if test might save one modulus operation.

Comment: 24,60  so the gcd is 12. If the input numbers are 60,24 the gcd remains the same.

Comment: I don't see any issue: https://ideone.com/v8CXhm What doesn't work for you?

Comment: When the if statement is not deleted, it does work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is not important whether `m` is greater than `n`. If `m` initially is less than `n` then in the first iteration of the do-while loop

```
do {
    r = m % n;
    m = n;
    n = r;
} while (r != 0);
```

`m` will be greater than `n` due to the statement

```
    m = n;
```

For example let's assume that `m` is equal to `2` and `n` is equal to `10`. So `r` equal to `m % n` will be equal to `2` and in fact these statements

```
m = n;
n = r;
```

swap `m` and `n` in the first iteration of the loop.

Answer (score 0):

There is nothing wrong with if() statement though...
The only thing that can maybe go wrong is misusing scanf(), apart from that your code works super fine